# Why does my mac's default terminal title flashes upon boot up and change?

Tags: terminal, zsh, title, undo, oh-my-zsh

**Note - This issue only happens in the mac's default terminal**

I ran `echo -n -e "\033]0;SERVER\007"` on my mac's built-in default terminal with zsh shell which resulted in this as the title:

`username -- username@devicename -- ~ -- -zsh -- 80x24`

which I am not pleased with, but I don't know how to undo this.

for example, running `~ node` results in `username -- node -- node -- node -- 80x24` as the title.

---

**Edit:**
The built-in terminal's title flashes really quickly upon boot up with these three titles in this sequence (I screen captured these microsecond flashes and wrote it out):

1. `username -- -zsh -- 80x24`
2. `username -- username@devicename -- ~ -- Python -m virtualenvwrapper.hook_load...`
3. `username -- username@devicename -- ~ -- -zsh -- 80x24`

It's odd if we find out that it's the virtualenvwrapper doing this, 'cause I only noticed this after running the echo command  *scratches head.

Comment: restart the terminal

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai it hasn't changed, I've restarted the terminal and the computer itself

Comment: @JosephKim Did you add that to a startup file (like `.zshrc`)? Nothing about that command itself is permanent; it just writes some bytes to standard output which your terminal emulator interprets as an instruction to modify its title bar rather than print to the screen literally. Even a new window opened without restarting the terminal emulator, let alone restarting your machine, should have whatever default the terminal emulator uses for the title text.

Comment: @JosephKim Also, that command alone would simply change the title text to "SERVER", not what you are showing. What terminal emulator are you using? It looks like *it* has been configured to show more information than usual in the title bar.

Comment: @chepner thank you for the helpful information, it does lead me to think that it's beyond just that echo script.  I have not added any additional script into any startup type files (script that is different prior to the issue).  Also, this issue is only coming up on the mac's default terminal which is where I ran the code.  I am currently using Hyper (and iTerm, but transitioning to Hyper).  The other terminals are not affected at all.  I must add that I did see that the title flashes upon boot and changes to the result I mentioned above.  I'll mention the flashing in the question itself.

Comment: `iTerm`, for example, has several checkboxes under the Appearance preferences pane that can add the window number, job name, and profile name the title bar in addition to what `\033]0;...\007` specifies. I assume Hyper has something similar.

Comment: Looking at the webpage for Hyper, I'm wondering if this is something very specific to Hyper.

Comment: I'm not sure this is even on-topic for Stack Overflow at this point. It seems to be about configuration of Hyper, which is probably better suited to superuser.com or apple.stackexchange.com (since Hyper appears to be Mac-only at the moment).

Comment: @chepner My mistake, let me clarify the confusion.  I'm only experiencing this issue on the default terminal. My other terminals are fine.  On Hyper: `username@devicename: ~`. On iTerm: `username@devicename: ~ (zsh)`.  I was confused 'cause you mentioned terminal emulators, my bad.